# How to pass setStyleSheet color as an item from a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I am using pyqt 4.11 and am trying to create a set of Labels using a loop and would like to change the color for each Label. However, the color remains as the default black.

```
red = (255,0,0)
orange = (255,128,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
green = (0,255,0)
loop = 0
NAME = ["apple","banana","strawberry","orange"]
NAME_COLOR = [green,yellow,red,orange]

while loop < len(NAME):
    lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    lbl.setText(NAME[loop])
    lbl.move(loop*50,120)
    lbl.setStyleSheet('QLabel { color: NAME_COLOR[loop]}')
    lbl.show()
    loop = loop + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set color of your label you need to use `setStyleSheet` as follow :

```
lbl.setStyleSheet('color: rgb{}'.format("(255,128,0)"))
```

Here is a working example of your program using ***PyQt4*** :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

red = (255, 0, 0)
orange = (255, 128, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        name = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "orange"]

        name_color = [green, yellow, red, orange]
        _dict = dict(zip(name, name_color))
        # _dict = {'apple': (0, 255, 0), 'banana': (255, 255, 0),
        #          'orange': (255, 128, 0), 'strawberry': (255, 0, 0)}

        for name, color in _dict.items():
            label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            label.setText(name)
            label.setStyleSheet('color: rgb{}'.format(str(color)))
            layout.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

***result :***

[image]